# Remove tag from HtmlTextWriter

Tags: c#, html, .net, string, htmltextwriter

I am receiving text to a function `public void LoadMarkup(HtmlTextWriter writer){}` and  I need to remove last `<tr>` tag from it.

The text I am getting is:

```
<table class="form">
        <tr>
            <td class="createLabel">Name:<span class="field">*</span></td><td><input type="text" maxlength="200" id="productTitle" name="productTitle" class="required" style="width: 250px;" /></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="createLabel">Account:<span class="field">*</span></td><td><select id="recognizedAccount" name="recognizedAccount" class="required">
                <option value="8a1dd4c7-8ddd-4632-aa81-6be29dc86d13">
                    Donation
                </option><option value="5617660d-4794-4cad-aab8-a04323faf68a">
                    Dues Account
                </option>
            </select></td>
        </tr><tr style="display: none;">
            <td class="createLabel">Deferral Method:</td><td><select id="deferralMethod" name="deferralMethod" class="required">
                <option value="e816071c-282d-46af-8c5d-ebecb8472b94">
                    None
                </option>
            </select></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="createLabel">Description:<span class="required-field">*</span></td><td><textarea id="productDescription" name="productDescription" class="required" rows="3" style="width: 250px;"></textarea></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="createLabel">Active:</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="productActive" name="productActive" /></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="createLabel">Expiration Date:<span class="required-field">*</span></td><td><span class="datePicker"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="productExpirationDate" name="productExpirationDate" class="required" style="width: 135px;" /></span></td>
        </tr><tr class="typeRates">
            <td class="createLabel">Rate:<span class="required-field">*</span></td><td><input id="5a2da3f6-c3e5-4cd0-a194-7a704c8f07e0_rate" name="5a2da3f6-c3e5-4cd0-a194-7a704c8f07e0_rate" class="required" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
```

I need to remove this text from Upper text:

```
<tr class="typeRates">
            <td class="createLabel">Rate:<span class="required-field">*</span></td><td><input id="5a2da3f6-c3e5-4cd0-a194-7a704c8f07e0_rate" name="5a2da3f6-c3e5-4cd0-a194-7a704c8f07e0_rate" class="required" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
```

I can not modify text before I am receiving it in function as this is coming from framework. Any one can help with it please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, nor the most robust, but perhaps give it a try:

```
public string RemoveLastTableRow(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
     // Create an array which contains each table row split
     string[] html = writer.ToString().Split(new string[] { "<tr>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

     // Return all the array indexes joined, except for the final index
     return string.Join("", html.Take(html.Count() - 1)); 
}
```

Comment: Even if I managed to remove `<tr>` from `writer` in a new string, I am not able to reassign new string in writer back. I can not return new string as the application needs to work with `writer` reference.
I have now simply hided the `<tr>`  and removed the required class from it with JQuery.

Comment: Fair enough, @NitinKatiyar. You may want to add that as an answer to your own question.