# How to remove first two columns and hyperlinks from repeater exported excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater, stringwriter, htmlwriter

I am exporting data to excel from repeater control, which contains some hyperlinks in multiple columns and  link buttons in first two columns. I want to remove all hyperlinks as well as remove or hide first two columns, when I export the data to excel from repeater control - "rptrExport". I am not getting any reference specially for repeater on internet. Below is my code:

**Export button click even:**

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=details.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();      
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);      
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        rptrExport.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

**Code in aspx class for repeater:**

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptrExport" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrExport_ItemDataBound">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>                                          
                                            <table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered" data-cookie="true"
                                                data-cookie-id-table="rptrExport" data-show-export="true" data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 90, ALL]" border="1" >
                                                <thead style="background-color: #787777; font-size:13px; border-color: white; color: white; white-space:nowrap; vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th data-sortable="true"> See Short desc</th>
                                                        <th data-sortable="true">See Long desc</th>
                                                        <th data-sortable="true">Website
                                                        </th></tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody style="font-size:13px; color:black">
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="text-align: center">
                                                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkShortDet"  runat="server" OnClick="lnkShortDet_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("sht") + "~"+Eval("shtSt") %>'><i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                                        <Triggers>
                                                            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkShortDet" />
                                                        </Triggers>
                                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="text-align: center">
                                                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                                          
                                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLongDet"  runat="server" OnClick="lnkLongDet_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("lng") + "~"+Eval("lngSt") %>'><i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                                        <Triggers>
                                                            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lng" />
                                                        </Triggers>
                                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnwebsite" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("web_url")%>'></asp:HiddenField>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lblWebsite" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("web_url")%>' OnClick="weburl_Click" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("web_url")%>'> <i class="fa fa-2x fa-file-pdf-o font-red"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                                </td>
 </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            </tbody> </table>
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it to string array then remove the wanted records.

Check below link, I think it can help you

[Remove tag from HtmlTextWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803527/remove-tag-from-htmltextwriter)